Diseño xml en la nueva version Jellyfish
en la nueva version Jellyfish, en las actividades xml, con el tema con ActionBar, este queda por encima de las vistas en la parte superior, es decir, las vistas, o el layout, quedan or debajo del actionbar en el margen superior. Como se soluciona?

Agrega tu layout.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
